# Retrieving final scene z-buffer and color buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es-2.0

I'm working on opengl 2.1 and opengl es 2.0. I want to implement Depth-of-field effect for whole scene. I know how to do this for single model with shader, but this would require all models to have shader with same code. Is there a way to retrieve final scene depth and color buffer and store them into textures so I could use them again with DOF shader? Or is it a bad idea?

[EDIT]
Finally got it working.
The initialization code looks like this:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer_);
glGenTextures(1, &colorBuffer_);
glGenTextures(1, &depthBuffer_);
//glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthBuffer_);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer_);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer_);
glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    0,
    GL_RGBA,
    width,
    height,
    0,
    GL_RGBA,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    NULL);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glFramebufferTexture2D(
    GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
    GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
    GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer_, 0);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthBuffer_);
glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    0,
    GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8,
    width,
    height,
    0,
    GL_DEPTH_STENCIL,
    GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8,
    NULL);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glFramebufferTexture2D(
    GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
    GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
    GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthBuffer_, 0);

//glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer_);
//glRenderbufferStorage(
//  GL_RENDERBUFFER,
//  GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24,
//  width,
//  height);
//glFramebufferRenderbuffer(
//  GL_FRAMEBUFFER,
//  GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,
//  GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer_);

GLenum status;
status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER);
switch(status) {
case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE:
    // Success.
break;
case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED:
    LOGE("Frame buffer format not supported.");
break;
default:
    LOGE("Framebuffer Error.");
}
```

And later when rendering first call:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer_);
```

Render scene, then call:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

And now anything can be rendered here using depthBuffer_ or colorBuffer_ as OpengGL texture handles.

Comment: I believe you can access Frame buffer objects (FBOs) in 2.1 using EXT or ARB functions. They may have even been promoted to the core, I can't remember.

If you can, then just render everything to an FBO. Attach textures to GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 and GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT. Then, bind the FBO as a texture and run your shader over it.

Comment: How do I bind FBO as a texture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a framebuffer object. They're part of OpenGL-ES-2 and are available as (well supported) extension to OpenGL-2.1.

See

https://github.com/datenwolf/codesamples/tree/master/samples/OpenGL/minimalfbo

for a minimal working example using extensions on desktop OpenGL-2.x

Comment: Thanks, my color buffer now works. But I still don't know how to use depth buffer. Now when I render the plane with color buffer and try to use gl_FragCoord.z I always get 0.0f. This is as it should be if there were no FBO, because plane is just in front of camera. But I would need gl_FragCoord.z values to be those of the scene rendered in FBO as if there was no plane at all. I don't know how to do that. Do I need to call some additional methods that would copy FBO depth buffer to current default buffer? Do I make any sense?

Comment: Use a depth texture instead of a renderbuffer. Then bind the depth texture to a second texture unit and read from that.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the code? I add color buffer like this: glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer_); and it works, so I tried glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthBuffer_); which, unfortunately, adds some other texture which is definitely not depth. How would I add depthBuffer_ as a texture?

Comment: Just figured out that I was not creating depth buffer the same way I was creating color buffer. I wasn't generating texture for it. Now it finally works! Thanks.